# Segmentation fault when writing to struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, segmentation-fault

I have a `struct` defined in my program as:

```
    struct memregion {
      void *from;
      void *to;
      int mode;
    }
```

I declare in my program, an array of this struct as `struct memregion regions[10]`. Then I pass it to a function as `get_mem_layout(regions, 10)` whose declaration is:

```
    void get_mem_layout(struct memregion *regions, int size)
```

However, when I try to write data to any member variable of the struct as

```
    regions[j].mode = 1;
```

OR

```
    void *addr;
    addr = (void *)0;
    regions[j].from = addr;
```

I receive a segmentation fault. I cannot determine why this is happening. Please help.

UPDATE:
Full code removed because it was part of an assignment. Problem was resolved through @paddy's answer.

Comment: Can you guarantee that `j < size`?

Comment: Please add more complete code, such as the loop.

Comment: Can you paste the code relevant to the variable `j`?

Comment: Yeah this description has to be incorrect, we need to see more code.  Also... why not simply assign `NULL` to `regions[n].from`?

Comment: Exactly where does your declaration of regions[10] occur?  Are you calling get_mem_layout() in the same block of code?

Comment: Are you sure of starting the for loop from 0 ( i.e., i=0 ) ?

Comment: @Mahesh: Yup. I have to scan the memory from 0x00000000

Comment: @WaqarHameed: You are setting your pointer to 0 at the start of your function... that will never work, it now points to an invalid memory address. The OS is not likely going to allow you to read arbitrary memory locations which do not belong to your process.  Memory location `0` will *never* be valid (i.e., `NULL == 0`). You need to specify your OS and then go find out what sort of API it provides for reading out of process memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why has nobody picked this up?  Or am I missing something?

In `get_mem_layout` one of the first things you did is this:

```
regions = 0;
```

Then you go on to access `regions` as an array...

Did you mean:

```
num_regions = 0;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This was indeed the problem. I know this is a horrible way to scan memory but this is a part of the assignment due to which I would have to remove the full code.

Comment: @WaqarHameed: Still though, your OS is (probably) going to hand you a segfault for trying to read outside your allocated portion of memory.  You can't just point a pointer wherever you like and start reading/writing.

Comment: Which I was handling through the SIGSEGV signal handler which was one of the objectives of the assignment.